# IPv6 client cannot connect to IPv6 server, cannot assign requested address

Tags: c, docker, ubuntu, tcp, ipv6

Re-using code [here](https://gist.github.com/jirihnidek/388271b57003c043d322) to reproduce a tcp client/server interaction.

The server initializes fine, begins listening for connections.

However, on running client `./client`, the client fails with message

> connect(): Cannot assign requested address

where the "failing" code from the link [above](https://gist.github.com/jirihnidek/388271b57003c043d322) (and also pasted below) is:

```
ret = connect(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
if (ret == -1) {
  perror("connect()");
  close(sock_fd);
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

When I run `ifconfig`, I do not see an IPv6 address. Is this a possible explanation? I am running an Ubuntu Docker image on an OSX machine.

The code is easily compilable/runnable with

```
gcc server.c -o server
gcc client.c -o client
./server 
./client
```

server.c

```
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
     
    #define CLIENT_QUEUE_LEN 10
    #define SERVER_PORT 7002
     
    int main(void)
    {
        int listen_sock_fd = -1, client_sock_fd = -1;
        struct sockaddr_in6 server_addr, client_addr;
        socklen_t client_addr_len;
        char str_addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        int ret, flag;
        char ch;
     
        /* Create socket for listening (client requests) */
        listen_sock_fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if(listen_sock_fd == -1) {
            perror("socket()");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
     
        /* Set socket to reuse address */
        flag = 1;
        ret = setsockopt(listen_sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &flag, sizeof(flag));
        if(ret == -1) {
            perror("setsockopt()");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        server_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
        server_addr.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
        server_addr.sin6_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
     
        /* Bind address and socket together */
        ret = bind(listen_sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
        if(ret == -1) {
            perror("bind()");
            close(listen_sock_fd);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
     
        /* Create listening queue (client requests) */
        ret = listen(listen_sock_fd, CLIENT_QUEUE_LEN);
        if (ret == -1) {
            perror("listen()");
            close(listen_sock_fd);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
     
        client_addr_len = sizeof(client_addr);
     
        while(1) {
            /* Do TCP handshake with client */
            client_sock_fd = accept(listen_sock_fd,
                    (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr,
                    &client_addr_len);
            if (client_sock_fd == -1) {
                perror("accept()");
                close(listen_sock_fd);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
     
            inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(client_addr.sin6_addr),
                    str_addr, sizeof(str_addr));
            printf("New connection from: %s:%d ...\n",
                    str_addr,
                    ntohs(client_addr.sin6_port));
     
            /* Wait for data from client */
            ret = read(client_sock_fd, &ch, 1);
            if (ret == -1) {
                perror("read()");
                close(client_sock_fd);
                continue;
            }
     
            /* Do very useful thing with received data :-) */
            ch++;
     
            /* Send response to client */
            ret = write(client_sock_fd, &ch, 1);
            if (ret == -1) {
                perror("write()");
                close(client_sock_fd);
                continue;
            }
     
            /* Do TCP teardown */
            ret = close(client_sock_fd);
            if (ret == -1) {
                perror("close()");
                client_sock_fd = -1;
            }
     
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

client.c

```
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
     
    #define SERVER_PORT 7002
     
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int sock_fd = -1;
        struct sockaddr_in6 server_addr;
        int ret;
        char ch = 'a';
     
        /* Arguments could be used in getaddrinfo() to get e.g. IP of server */
        (void)argc;
        (void)argv;
     
        /* Create socket for communication with server */
        sock_fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (sock_fd == -1) {
            perror("socket()");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
     
        /* Connect to server running on localhost */
        server_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
        inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &server_addr.sin6_addr);
        server_addr.sin6_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
     
        /* Try to do TCP handshake with server */
        ret = connect(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
        if (ret == -1) {
            perror("connect()");
            close(sock_fd);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
     
        /* Send data to server */
        ret = write(sock_fd, &ch, 1);
        if (ret == -1) {
            perror("write");
            close(sock_fd);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
     
        /* Wait for data from server */
        ret = read(sock_fd, &ch, 1);
        if (ret == -1) {
            perror("read()");
            close(sock_fd);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
     
        printf("Received %c from server\n", ch);
     
        /* DO TCP teardown */
        ret = close(sock_fd);
        if (ret == -1) {
            perror("close()");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
     
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So when I ran the code on a non docker container (the host) which has an IPv6 address based on running `ifconfig`, I get the output

> Received b from server

which appears to confirm my suspicion that the container does not support IPv6.

If anyone cares to elaborate, they are welcome to.

Answer (score 0):

Your server_addr.sin6_flowspec and other members of that struct are being left uninitialized.

Start by zero'ing out your `server_addr` instances before passing it to `connect`.

Either this at declaration time:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 server_addr = {0};
```

Or a memset call to fill it with all zeros before you start assigning the members of that struct values.

```
memset(&server_addr, '\0', sizeof(server_addr));
```

I believe that will fix your issue. If not, read on.

If the above doesn't resolve your issue, it's likely because you aren't properly initializing the sin6_flowspec or other members of the sockaddr_in6 struct that aren't in the ipv4 sockaddr_in struct.  You can leverage getaddrinfo to do the heavy work for you to properly fill in these fields.

```
int result = 0;
addrinfo* resultList = NULL;
addrinfo hints = {};

hints.ai_family = AF_INET6;
hints.ai_flags |= AI_NUMERICHOST; // comment this line out if getaddrinfo fails
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

int result = getaddrinfo("::1", NULL, &hints, &resultList);

if ((result == 0) && (resultList->ai_family == AF_INET6))
{
    memcpy(&server_addr, resultList->ai_addr, sizeof(sockaddr_in6));
    server_addr.sin6_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
}
else
{
   // fail
}

if (resultList)
{
    freeaddrinfo(&resultList);
}
resultList = NULL;
```